# Retrieve key from automatically assigned ID which has been passed through URL in GAE, using ndb and python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore

I've been struggling with this for hours and tried everything!

So basically

I have a class called City:

```
class City(ndb.Model):
    _parent = None
    city = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

When i make a new city, it is given an automatic ID, such as 6438740092256256

Later on i want to add a Restaurant entity to this city as a child. So I have passed the city ID in the url, like this:

http://www.edkjfsk.com/addrestaurant/6438740092256256

which leads to this bit of code

```
class PostRestaurant(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, resource):
        key = ????
```

where resource is 6438740092256256

What i want to do is to be able to retrieve the key using the 6438740092256256 from the url. However every single approach i have tried results in an unknown error.

Ive tried everything, including key = :

```
City.get_by_id(int(resource))

ndb.Key(City, resource).get()

ndb.Key('City', int(resource))
```

etc.

Comment: The problem might have been putting key= ???. By putting r = Restaurant(parent=ndb.Key('City', int(resource))) i solved the problem. Phewww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting urlsafe string here.

```
this_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=resource)
query_result_as_entity = this_key.get()
```

After converting urlsafe string to key, you can just do get() on it.